# Where is local.xml in M2

Tags: magento2, layout, local.xml, magento2.2.2

I'm just starting **Magento 2** and I see a lot of things that are gone !

Can somone can explain me this with the **best practices** of course:

I inquired and I found that: the layout **xml** are loaded according to the layout handles

**ex:** if we want add some block to the home page, we should create `cms_index_index.xml` and we add the needed block inside right ? so where is exactly the path to create it.

**ex2:** supposing that i have my module `app/code/Am/Prince/view/frontend/layout/prince_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Am\Prince\Block\Block" name="home-block1" template="home-block1.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If I need to display this block `home-block1` also in **home page** can I declare it in this **xml** ?

.So where is **local.xml** like M1 ?, wonderfully we have to declare it once and we put all the changes on it with prefexing the layout handle and the block inside something like:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
    ...
</cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add your custom block on homepage you need to do this things.

1. create `cms_index_index.xml` file at following location.

   app/code/Am/Prince/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml
2. Now add block code into that file like this.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
>     <body>
>         <referenceContainer name="content">
>             <block class="Am\Prince\Block\Block" template="Am_Prince::home-block1.phtml"/>
>         </referenceContainer>
>     </body>
> </page>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

There is no local.xml equivalent for layout in Magento 2.  There are, however, a couple of ways to solve your requirement:

1. If you're only looking to add the block on 2 pages then separate layout files should be used.  For example cms_index_index.xml to add it to the homepage.
2. If you want the block to appear on every page in your website you can create a default.xml in your module and reference your block in there.  The path for this would be app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/default.xml